# jQuery codes won't work on new tags that created with "after"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using "after" method to add new elements to the page
When I click on `<i>` in `<label>`
It will do the toggleClass thing
but when I add new `<label>` using `after` in jQuery
the new `<label>` won't toggleClass
any solutions?

here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".wrapper form label i").click(function () {
        $(this).parent("label").toggleClass("activeLabel");
});
    $(".hamMenu").click(function () {
        $(".fixMenu").toggleClass("fixMenuActive");
    });
    $(".fixMenuItems ul li").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("fixMenuItemActive");
        $(this).siblings(".fixMenuItems ul li").removeClass("fixMenuItemActive");
    });
    $(".addImg").click(function () {
        $("label:last").after("<label for=''>Photo<i class='fas fa-ellipsis-v'></i><input type='file'> </label>");
        $("label").not(":last").addClass("activeLabel");
    });
    $(".addTxt").click(function () {
        $("label:last").after("<label for=''>Text<i class='fas fa-ellipsis-v'></i><textarea cols='30' rows='10'></textarea> </label>");
    })

});
```

Comment: share your HTML portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for a click on the parent:

```
$(".wrapper form").on("click", "label i", function () {
    $(this).parent("label").toggleClass("activeLabel");
});
```